# How to check the file is in check in mode or not in c#

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting the document of particular document library of a sharepoint site in C#.
I want to check whether the file in checkin mode or in checkout mode . how can i do that. can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, change parameter name as needed

```
if (spDestinationFile.Item.ParentList.ForceCheckout == true)
```

Have a look at [this post](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2010/01/adding-watermark-to-pdf-file-from.html) about how it can be used.